# jQuery for JSON

Tags: java, jquery, json

We have JSON message and we are trying to extract all label and values from the JSON message by using jQuery (http://www.jsonquerytool.com/). We tried "$..[label,value] ,$..['label','value'],$..label,value" etc.. But no success. Could anyone of you please help me to fetch label & value in one query.
JSON Message :

```js
[
  {
    "key": "A",
    "label": "Question 1",
    "value": "Test",
    "tags": [],
    "valueType": "TEXT",
    "displayValue": [
      "Test"
    ],
    "assignedToProcessInput": false,
    "confidential": false
  },
  {
    "key": "B",
    "label": "Question 2",
    "value": "Ignore",
    "tags": [],
    "valueType": "TEXT",
    "displayValue": [
      "Ignore"
    ],
    "assignedToProcessInput": false,
    "confidential": false
  }
]
```

Comment: Query Type Should be : JSON Path (dchester 1.0.2)

Comment: jQuery and "JSON Query Tool" have no relationship other than a coincidentally similar name.

Comment: ok, But one of my tool which i am using for my project is aligned with http://www.jsonquerytool.com/. i.e; whatever query which is working on that browser will work on my tool. That's why i have given that reference

Comment: It does sound like you're looking for JsonPath. Proper tagging will help you get useful answers. You also haven't shown the code where you're trying to put those expressions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will tag JSON path. Since, i am using confidential tool....I couldn't share the exact screenshots. Please ignore. FYI, $..value retrieved all values (Simillarly $..label retrieved all label values). Please help us, if you can. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution using `map`

```js
var json = [
  {
    "key": "A",
    "label": "Question 1",
    "value": "Test",
    "tags": [],
    "valueType": "TEXT",
    "displayValue": [
      "Test"
    ],
    "assignedToProcessInput": false,
    "confidential": false
  },
  {
    "key": "B",
    "label": "Question 2",
    "value": "Ignore",
    "tags": [],
    "valueType": "TEXT",
    "displayValue": [
      "Ignore"
    ],
    "assignedToProcessInput": false,
    "confidential": false
  }
];

json.map(item => {
  console.log(item.label, ": ", item.value );
});
```

If you want to store the message the please use below code

```js
var json = [
  {
    "key": "A",
    "label": "Question 1",
    "value": "Test",
    "tags": [],
    "valueType": "TEXT",
    "displayValue": [
      "Test"
    ],
    "assignedToProcessInput": false,
    "confidential": false
  },
  {
    "key": "B",
    "label": "Question 2",
    "value": "Ignore",
    "tags": [],
    "valueType": "TEXT",
    "displayValue": [
      "Ignore"
    ],
    "assignedToProcessInput": false,
    "confidential": false
  }
];

var msgVal = [];

json.map(item => {
  msg.push({
   label: item.label,
   value: item.value
  );
});

console.log(msg);
```

Updated solution

```js
[
  {
    "key": "A",
    "label": "Question 1",
    "value": "Test",
    "tags": [],
    "valueType": "TEXT",
    "displayValue": [
      "Test"
    ],
    "assignedToProcessInput": false,
    "confidential": false
  },
  {
    "key": "B",
    "label": "Question 2",
    "value": "Ignore",
    "tags": [],
    "valueType": "TEXT",
    "displayValue": [
      "Ignore"
    ],
    "assignedToProcessInput": false,
    "confidential": false
  }
]

$..label
```

Comment: May i know, what is the compiler you used ? Because, I would need to build JQUERY as per my question to fetch label and value. I tried to use your code on JQUERYTOOL which is not working.

Comment: I solved the problem using pure JavaScript and jQuery is nothing but a framework which is written on top of JavaScript. What error you are getting now?

Comment: I am using "http://www.jsonquerytool.com/ "(Query Type : JSON Path dchester 1.0.2) which is aligned with one of my product to compile your code. It not giving any output. It simply gives null (empty object)

Comment: @RaghuramGuggilam `$..label` to access label

Comment: Yes, $..label works to retrieve only label. I would like to retrieve both label and value in single query. :( Please help me, if you can. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code JSON in http://www.jsonquerytool.com/

```
{
"array": [
    {
    "key": "A",
    "label": "Question 1",
    "value": "Test",
    "tags": [],
    "valueType": "TEXT",
    "displayValue": [
      "Test"
    ],
    "assignedToProcessInput": false,
    "confidential": false
  },
  {
    "key": "B",
    "label": "Question 2",
    "value": "Ignore",
    "tags": [],
    "valueType": "TEXT",
    "displayValue": [
      "Ignore"
    ],
    "assignedToProcessInput": false,
    "confidential": false
  }
]
```

}

query type = javascript

```
input.array[1]
```

and then this result

```
{
"key": "B",
"label": "Question 2",
"value": "Ignore",
"tags": [],
"valueType": "TEXT",
"displayValue": [
    "Ignore"
],
"assignedToProcessInput": false,
"confidential": false
```

}

Comment: I need label and value in output

Comment: [
  input.array[1].label,
  input.array[1].value
]

output
[
    "Question 2",
    "Ignore"
]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need something dynamic. Here we are passing "1" as a static parameter which is not useful in my scenario. :(